# What are the risks to an app in supporting older iOS versions?

Tags: appsec, ios

I'm a developer working on an application that supports minimum iOS 10. It concerns me that we are supporting such an old version of iOS but the client wishes to support customers with older iPhones that may not support the latest iOS. I want to understand what's the risk to the app in supporting older iOS versions.

Comment: locally installed app? web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you get a client to install is out of your hands. It could be installed in an emulator or in a reverse engineering rig or on a rooted device. Or on an older and vulnerable OS. This means that the app is outside of your control and anything can happen to it.

It can be decomposed, traffic can be inspected, encryption can be broken. Either intentionally by the user or by a malicious process. The device's controls limit how far that can go, but it cannot prevent everything.

So, the *security* risks to your app and the data on the app is not greater for running on an old OS. There may be other UX and operational risks, but that would be off-topic.